# confirmation dialog box in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

In web applicaiton, i am trying to write the code like this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(confirm('Are you sure to delete?')){}else{return false}");

    Response.Write("hi");
}
```

but when first time I click on button it is showing "hi" without confirmation, second time onwords it is showing confirmation.

Comment: That is because Attribute is getting added after you click it! And will be executed when you click second time! You need to have button attributes updated outside 'button1_click' event.. preferably OnLoad()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your JavaScript into the markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm(...)" />
```

Comment: yeah, but i want check in the code itself, how can i do, i want to give the confirm to the user if he click on yes it will proceed other wise it stop the proceeding the code

Comment: i am checking in the button click even. if data is in databse i am confirming to user if u want to insert if he click on yes it is inserted if not it not insert

Comment: @Ssasidhar: I'd recommend to check on page rendering, then you can decide what render and how.

Answer (score 2):

What you are currently doing is adding an onclick attribute in javascript the first time that the button is clicked. Then you are outputting "hi" every time that the button is clicked.

You need to add the onclick attribute earlier in the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), perhaps in Page_Load.